# How to create a PDF identical to window.print()?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm working on a website that is adapted for printing using `@media print` and I want to create a PDF with the identical layout as when printing the page.

When calling `window.print()`, it is easy to click to download the PDF in the browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) from the Print Preview window which gives the desired result but is not user friendly.

I want to instead create an easily accessible button which has this exact same behaviour of downloading a PDF with the print CSS layout and the current HTML element values.

I have looked at several solutions for creating PDF's, such as [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf) and [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), but they lack certain CSS support and it's tricky to get dynamically set html element values to also be printed since I call these functions from the backend.

So, shouldn't this be a simple problem to solve? Do I really have to use libraries like wkhtmltopdf or dompdf to get the desired result?

Comment: You could prerender the PDF's and then just download them with Javascript.

Comment: "So, shouldn't this be a simple problem to solve? ". Well PDF is a complicated file format, and then there's the issue of translating HTML and the accompanying CSS rules into rules which would work in the PDF format, where they may or may not be any direct equivalent concept, and then there's your dynamic content. So what do you think? Of course you don't _have_ to use a library for this, but given that even the established libraries have their limitations as you've noted, then I think you'll soon get bored of re-implementing the same functionality and experiencing the same issues.

Comment: @lonut I think the OP is saying that they want to achieve this through vanilla JS without the use of any library.

Comment: @NoelSchenk how would you pre-render the PDF? If the OP could do that, then there would be no question. Based on my interpretation of the question, I'm assuming dynamic data is involved hence the OP wanting to create the PDF.

Comment: @Script47 shure this would be pretty simple just download the PDF's manualy and upload them to the server. Then add a link to it's data. If it containts dynamic data it would not be posible.

Comment: @Script47 that would not be possible since the users create the content that will then be made into a PDF, there is not time for manual upload to the server using the built in browser functionality(if this is what you suggest).

Comment: @ADyson So is it safe to assume that all the browsers have their internal tools which are excellent at converting HTML -> PDF with a perfect visual mapping, and are unwilling to share these tools?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox are both open-source, so there's nothing stopping you from looking at what goes on. But that may not be the process. When you open the browser's print preview window, the browser sends it to a print window. At that point, the HTML has been rendered as an image into the preview window, in a format that printers can understand. Then you choose either a printer or the send-to-PDF option. The list of options you get is determined by the printer drivers installed on your machine. The PDF option is implemented like a printer driver i.e. it doesn't use HTML as its source data.